# What kind of attack vectors are made possible as a result of Java being hopelessly intertwined with Android?

Tags: encryption, linux, android, java, ios

"All the security of Linux … plus Java! “Java: The malware compatibility layer of choice” Android can be engineered for security, but when you’re done you have a hermetically sealed self contained comms device — not a smartphone"

Excerpt from COMSEC Beyond Encryption by TheGrugq

http://grugq.github.io/presentations/COMSEC%20beyond%20encryption.pdf

What does TheGrugq mean by this?

Comment: FYI: Is X more secure than Y gets posted often. And as often as they get posted they get closed since they are too broad or primarily opinion based. So if you are just looking for an explanation of their statement you might want to change how you ask this question in the subject.

Comment: Yes, Brad is right, you might want to change the subject to ask "What are the Android malware vulnerabilities referred to here?" or something to that effect.  BTW, welcome to the site!

Comment: Your edit comes off as a bit like can X be as secure as Y. Which is asking the same question differently. I would suggest something more along the lines of @NH.'s  suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is essentially a huge Java virtual machine. There is the core operating system, the kernel running a virtualization system called Dalvik, and Dalvik runs a bunch of applications. Java is easy to exploit, many bugs have been discovered since Androids inception that allow breaking out of dalvik sandbox, you can google "Android dalvik CVEs" or "Android JVM CVEs" to see some examples. All the underlying security of linux is made less effective because of this. In 2010 security researchers were able to upload a malicious Angry birds game app to Android Marketpkace that invisibly downloads other apps without users permissions. Yes Android CAN be hardened for security, but not without compromising the user experieince.